# ActiveEffects - Completly Disable Particles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can you summon a mob with a potion effect (using the ActiveEffects tag), but without the  annoying particles? I know about Ambient, however, that does not help me with my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `ShowParticles` tag is set to 0, particles will be disabled for that effect entirely. The datatype, being byte, **must** be declared correctly for this tag. To do so you append the numerical value with a "b":

```
/summon Creeper ~ ~1 ~ {ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:200,ShowParticles:0b}]}
```

Comment: You have my thanks! I've seen ShowParticles before, however, no source mentioned the "b".

Comment: @Seikatsu7 If you found the answer useful, mark it as correct, it rewards the user and helps people with the same problem find it faster.